# Организация проекта в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть проект сервиса, он на стадии постановки тз.
Нужно реализовать несколько интерфейсов:

- Публичный интерфейс (видят все)
- Личный кабинет клиента (видит только клиент)
- Личный кабинет менеджера (он взаимодействует с клиентами)
- Интерфейс администратора (он дает права менеджерам и собирает их статистику)

В yii2 есть модули, в advanced шаблоне из коробки есть разделение на backend-frontend.

Как разграничить вью-контроллеры разных типов пользователей в Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 2):

1) вам необходимо создать таблицу ролей

2) роли необходимо джойнить с пользователем

3) далее необходимо создать middleware (например IsAdmin, IsManager, etc...), которые будут смотреть наличие ролей у текущего пользователя

4) в файле ротера (api, web) обернуть роуты, которые необходимо засекьюрить в конструкицю Route::group

вот и все =)

Comment: Стоит ли разделять контроллеры и view для разных ролей?
Если да, то как?

Comment: Это уже как удобно вам. По моему субъективному мнению - стоит, далее поддержка будет легче и понятнее.