# Как управлять пользователями с разными ролями

Tags: php, laravel, role

Суть заключается в следующем.
Есть студенческий сайт. Пользователи по ролям админ/топ/менеджер/препод/студент.

Как лучше разрабатывать структуру.
Например есть **группа** в которую входят студенты и преподы. В целом у них возможности +- одинаковые, просматривать участников, просматривать домашнее задание... 
Но препод может задать домашнее задание, а студенты могут только прислать решение.

Вопрос в том как лучше сделать?
Создаем отдельные контролеры для препода и студента и отдельные View, и рулим их возможности там.

Или же создаем один контролер для группы к которому даем доступ для препода и студента и нарезаем им там возможности в одном месте.

Как лучше реализовывать, что бы  в будущем при масштабировании системы, структура была более ясной и понятной.

Пример с группой это одна из многих возможностей.

**Спасибо большое!**

Comment: на мой взгляд вам нужны просто [роли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867880/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-laravel?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Техника которая вам нужна называется ACL (access control list). Вот ссылка на документация которая вам нужна: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-acl/3.0